# Visual Studio shows a message "Please wait for the task to complete before closing" when I attempt to quit it or close the solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Per the title, I see the following message when attempting to quit VS or close the current solution:

[image]

There isn't any indication of what the task might be, or where to find more info on it. The Task List window appears empty:

[image]

There is no build in progress

The Windows Task Manager task list seems curious given that this is a console app, and the only thing it does that touches web stuff is use Flurl to read a JSON response from an API:

[image]

The most recent significant thing that happened during debug was an exception during reading or parsing the API response.

The only other possibly relevant thing I can see (and the thing that caused me to want to restart VS) is that when the code is stopped on a breakpoint, I can't resume execution - I can single step with F10 but I can't resume the code with F5 (pressing it causes no change), and there is no "▷ Continue" button in the ribbon:

[image]

Does anyone know what this "task" VS is performing might relate to, and if it's one of the child processes, whether they can be force quit without any risk of corrupting the IDE or the project?

Comment: `taskkill /f /im devenv.exe`

Comment: Your "stop" button is red.  So VS thinks there's still some sort of debug going on. Have you tried clicking that?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more clear that the first messagebox appears when not debugging. I can (could - Windows Update force restarted the machine overnight so it's gone now) start and stop debugging no problem, but I can't Continue (even though I can step) and when debugging is stopped, attempting to quite VS results in the messagebox first shown..